# Searching iCloud on a browser (on a windows machine) using tags

Tags: icloud, windows

I'm sorry if this is a very basic thing that I'm asking - I'm primarily a windows user :-(
Can I search my files stored in iCloud but accessed on a web browser on a windows machine (Firefox, Opera, Safari) by using tags? I can't find any way to do it but don't know if I'm missing anything.
I'm pretty sure I can't search in my File Explorer iCloud folder on the Windows machine.
Thanks in advance
B

Comment: I can't test this, I don't use iCloud Docs, but you're right that Windows cannot see tags. It doesn't know what they are, although files placed on Windows machines over file sharing from Mac still retain the tags. These can be seen if you use SMB to view the files from a Mac.

Comment: Thank you Tetsujin. Could you clarify what SMB is? Sorry for my ignorance! :-(

Comment: "File Sharing" in short. It's a universal standard used by Mac & Windows. It's short for 'Server Message Block' but you don't need to know that.